# How can i make url by coordinate of clicked Marker in Google map api

Tags: ajax, google-maps, jsp

I tried to save user's click coordinate data of Google map

I'm using JSP and Javascript

I can change URL like below

when user click the map i can get lat and lng

```
selected_Latitude = latLng.lat()
selected_Longitude = latLng.lng()       


window.location.assign("myurl/map.jsp?lat="+selected_Latitude + "&lng=" + selected_Longitude)
```

It works fine, but Browser keep reload page.

but i want to change url not reload page again. like maps.google.com

I think i have to use Ajax, but i don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work around to mark the clicked position without reloading the page. I am not sure why you are trying to lat & lan in URL using `window.location`. Just check whether if it's useful.

I have used center at Columbia. Please find the code below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map;
   // Creates the map
   function initialize() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 10,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.6439217, -87.0828474), //For Columbia
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
   }

   // This function takes an array argument containing a list of marker data
  function generateMarkers(locations) {
     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });
   }
 }
</script>

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
    var address = "Spring Hill";
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
    var loc2 = [];
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {    
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                loc2.push("[" + event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng() +"]");
                locations1 = "[" + loc2 + "]";
                generateMarkers(eval(locations1));
            } 
            else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

Also please find  the working [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/nfh92nkf/2/) for your reference. Let me know if it's helped you.